# Searching for multiple pairs of letters in a string (Ruby)

Tags: regex, ruby, string

`str = "88Bifk8hB8BB8BBBB888chl8BhBfd"`
I would like to find all pairs in the string containing "B8" *and* "8B", they must be found and returned in order.
str should return `"8BB8B8B88B"`

so far I have tried:
`str.scan("B8")`
which finds all the "B8" combinations, but this method doesn't allow for another argument for "8B".
This might need a regex search but have tried some different combinations which either don't work or still just return a single combination, i.e. "B8".

Comment: `"88Bifk8hB8BB8BBBB888chl8BhBfd".scan(/B8|8B/).join #=> "8BB8B8B88B"`. The question for which this question is claimed to be a duplicate does not appear to answer your question. I therefore am voting to reopen your question.

Comment: I inadvertently downvoted your question. Please make a small edit so that I can correct my error and then delete this comment. Please also leave me a comment saying you've done so.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for helping to reopen this! I was fairly sure the initial response didn't solve my question, but doubted myself as i'm very new to both stackoverflow and coding. This solution works great for me. Thanks all!

Comment: You reached 15 points, now you can upvote questions and answers that you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```rb
text.scan(/8B|B8/).join()
```

See [regex proof](https://rubular.com/r/JAmUVicd4hnzJF) and [Ruby proof](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vyS1okTBVkHdwsIpMy3bIsPJwgmEgISFRXJGjoVThlNaijpXgQJIoV5xcmKehr6FU42Thb6mXlZ@Zp6G5v//AA).

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `8B` | '8B' |
| `|` | OR |
| `B8` | 'B8' |